# Real time text filtering

Tags: java, android, arrays

What happens is that currently my filter searches for one word and I need to search for texts with more than one word and I don't know how to do it.

´´´

```
    Txtbuscar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            //String palabra = Txtbuscar.getText().toString().trim();
            String palabra = charSequence.toString().trim();
            //Filtra los clientes según el texto que se va ingresando en tiempo real
            if (clientesAdapter != null) {
                clientesAdapter.getFilter().filter(palabra);
                // Resetea la selección del Spinner
                ClienteAfectado.setSelection(0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }
    });
```

´´´

I don't know what I'm missing :s, I debugged the theme and according to andorid studio the variable text is taking all the text even if they are 2 words, but still my spinner doesn't fill me with the results, basically it says that they don't exist.

My idea is that this editText will help me to filter the results.

Comment: Try to move all your processing from `onTextChanged` to `afterTextChanged` and assign `palabra` to `editable.toString().trim()`. Maybe it will help.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work either, finally I made a method to manage the filter with a button but it's not filling my spinner hahahaha

Answer (score 1):

```
Txtbuscar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        String inputText = charSequence.toString().trim();
        String[] keywords = inputText.split("\\s+");

        Log.d("TextWatcher", "Input keywords: " + Arrays.toString(keywords));

        if (clientesAdapter != null) {
            clientesAdapter.getFilter().filterByKeywords(keywords);
            ClienteAfectado.setSelection(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    }
});

## let's verify the filtering process within your adapter's filterByKeywords ##
public void filterByKeywords(String[] keywords) {
    filteredClientes.clear();

    for (Cliente cliente : originalClientes) {
        boolean matchesAllKeywords = true;

        for (String keyword : keywords) {
            if (!cliente.getName().toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toLowerCase())) {
                matchesAllKeywords = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (matchesAllKeywords) {
            filteredClientes.add(cliente);
        }
    }

    Log.d("Filter", "Filtered clients: " + filteredClientes.toString());

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}



----------
```